# How to create Numeric KB interface with previous, next and done button

Tags: xcode4.5

I was on website on my iPhone and I encounter websites' guestbook. with those textFields. my keyboard appearance was totally change as you can see in screen below. 
[image: image of KB]

I am having many text fields in my app, I am wondering if I can create anything like that. 
As I am new to development, still unknown what are the limits. 
Can anyone guide me to right direction or to right documentation. 
Is there is some regular way or its just total customization over Keybard.
I have one more doubt, does it matter what kind of keyboard is popping up as my all fields have numeric keyboard.

Comment: This Question can be close, As I found that UIToolbar control can help. if anyone having the same question, please use the UIToolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just wanted to be helpful to someone who is following the same learning curve as me.

To achieve the affect in screenshot in question. UIToolbar control can be used to make those buttons. after the you need to just make this toolbar appear and disappear with the keyboard.

To make previous and next button work, you can use the tag property of textfield. on clicking on previous or next you can focus to previous or next text field. 
Sorry about not posting code as I have not coded it yet but wanted to give pointer to anyone, who is looking.